# pyserial gets no response from the bootloader in embedded device

Tags: python, pyserial

I have an embedded device configured to boot in to the bootloader which expects to communicate with the user on the USART1 after reboot.

This works if I open a serial terminal application *(cutecom)* and connect to the device `/dev/ttyUSB0` using:

- 115200 baud rate,
- 8 data bits,
- even parity
- 1 stop bit

After connecting I reboot the device, send `0x7f` to the bootloader and bootloader acknowledges with `0x79`. Here is how it looks:

[image]

This works flawlessly.

---

Now, I want to automate this with the following python script which was supposed to automatically connect to the device, write `0x7f` and then continue to read in order to receive the expected acknowledge `0x79` from the bootloader. But, acknowledge never comes...

```py
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial
s = serial.Serial(
    port="/dev/ttyUSB0",
    baudrate=115200,
    bytesize=8,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=1,
    timeout=120
)

s.write(bytes([0x7f]))

while True:
    readData = s.read()  
    print(readData)
```

What am I missing. Isn't this simple enough... I was thinking that bootloader responds too fast. Is this possible? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, embedded device was too fast and python wasn't able to catch the initial acknowledge. It helps to start two processes and after we start reading we send a command `0x7f`.

```py
import serial
import multiprocessing

s = serial.Serial(
    port=r"/dev/ttyUSB0",
    baudrate=115200,
    bytesize=8,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=1,
    timeout=120
)

def readSerial(serialConn):
    while True:
        readData = serialConn.read()
        readDataHex = ""
        if readData:
            for byte in readData:
                readDataHex = readDataHex + ' ' + hex(byte)
            print(f"RX:{readDataHex}")

def writeSerial(serialConn):
    serialConn.write(bytes([0x7F]))
    print("TX: 0x7F")

readProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=readSerial, args=(s,))
sendProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=writeSerial, args=(s,))

readProcess.start()
sendProcess.start()

# Wait for the reading process to finish (send process will exit after sending)
readProcess.join()
```